# grep in file and replace string

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file with iostat information about my disk in one line, but the time stay at the above line. When I use grep I can collect these two lines. But I want to put or replace the time in the same line of the disk informations.

```
grep -E "sda|22-09" iostat.dat
22-09-2015 15:36:10
sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
22-09-2015 15:36:12
sda               0,00     2,00    0,50   17,00     0,00     0,07     8,91     0,13    7,20    0,00    7,41   5,94  10,40
22-09-2015 15:36:14
sda               0,00    10,50    0,00    3,00     0,00     0,06    38,67     0,07   24,00    0,00   24,00  24,00   7,20
22-09-2015 15:36:16
sda               0,00     5,00    0,00    5,50     0,00     0,03    12,36     0,10   18,55    0,00   18,55  18,55  10,20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this with GNU sed:

```
| sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

Output:

```
22-09-2015 15:36:10 sda               0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00   0,00
22-09-2015 15:36:12 sda               0,00     2,00    0,50   17,00     0,00     0,07     8,91     0,13    7,20    0,00    7,41   5,94  10,40
22-09-2015 15:36:14 sda               0,00    10,50    0,00    3,00     0,00     0,06    38,67     0,07   24,00    0,00   24,00  24,00   7,20
22-09-2015 15:36:16 sda               0,00     5,00    0,00    5,50     0,00     0,03    12,36     0,10   18,55    0,00   18,55  18,55  10,20
```

Answer (score 2):

To join consecutive lines, use `paste`:

```
grep -E "sda|22-09" iostat.dat | paste - -
```